# Connect to Bluetooth Device with ouit modifying the Manifest file

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth

I need to connect to a number of diffrent blueTooth devices and I've got a lot of help doing that. Latest this : [Connect to Bluetooth Device / how to set the rfcomm capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129649/connect-to-bluetooth-device-how-to-set-the-rfcomm-capability/27130314).

this question is a spinoff of my latest question: Can I avoid the makeing changes in the manifest file. Can it be done some other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to connect several bluetooth devices, however not without changing the Manifest. If you don't specify your device id's or services in there, the OS will not give you the capability to connect them through Bluetooth.Rfcomm or Bluetooth.Gatt.